# Web API ODATA - Does we have to load all the records to enable filtering using Odata?

Tags: entity-framework, web, ado.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am developing an API using ASP.Net WEB API + Odata to query and filter those data. But rather than using entity framework to retrieve data,i am using ADO.Net to get data from Stored Procedures.

> Its working fine but to apply Odata filtering first i have to retrieve
>   all the records from the database. If the table cotains more than 1
>   million records then the server will just hang.

This is a sample code i am using,

```
List<ApplicationProduct> res = applicationBL.GetApplicationProducts(key, SyndicateKey);
    if (res.Count > 0)
        {
            Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount = res.Count();
            GenarateNextLink(key, res.Count, Convert.ToString(Request.RequestUri).Contains("$top"));
            SetCacheDuration(1);
            return Ok(res.AsQueryable());
        }
```

So i have to find a way to generate the query dynamically so filters are applied first and then we dont have to load all the records from the database. Is it possible using OData ? Or is there any other way?

Thank You.